# JSP Googlemaps taglib not found, where have I gone wrong?

Tags: java, jsp, google-maps, netbeans, taglib

I'm trying to add Google Maps onto my JSPs by using the Googlemaps taglib.

I've added this into my maven pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lamatek</groupId>
        <artifactId>googlemaps</artifactId>
        <version>0.98c</version>
        <scope>provided<>/scope
    </dependency>
```

This then included the `googlemaps-0.98c` library under my project libraries in NetBeans, I right clicked and selected `Manually install artifact` and located the googlemaps.jar file I had downloaded.

I've then added this into my taglibs file

```
<%@taglib prefix="googlemaps" uri="/WEB-INF/googlemaps" %>
```

And have then included this where I actually want to show a map on my jsp

```
    <googlemaps:map id="map" width="250" height="300" version="2" type="STREET"
                    zoom="12">
        <googlemaps:key domain="localhost" key="xxxx"/>
        <googlemaps:point id="point1" address="74 Connors Lane" city="Elkton"
                          state="MD" zipcode="21921" country="US"/>
        <googlemaps:marker id="marker1" point="point1"/>
    </googlemaps:map>
```

But when I load up my application, I get the following error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/dashboard.jsp(1,1) /jsp/common/taglibs.jsp(6,56) PWC6117: File "/WEB-INF/googlemaps" not found

root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/common/taglibs.jsp(6,56) PWC6117: File "/WEB-INF/googlemaps" not found
```

Have I missed something simple? I'm unable to spot what I've done wrong so far..

Comment: Are you including the tag lib directive in the jsp?

Comment: Yeah, I have all my taglibs in a separate file, then use this at the top of my jsps : `<%@include file="/jsp/common/taglibs.jsp" %>`

Comment: Is `<scope>provided<>/scope` a copy/paste error or actually what's in your POM? Because that ain't no valid XML.

Comment: @Bears, think it was a copy/paste, but I've removed it and it makes no difference.

Comment: This is not JSTL taglib. This is the Googlemaps taglib. The JSTL taglib is here: http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/ I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you do this:

```
<%@taglib prefix="googlemaps" uri="/WEB-INF/googlemaps" %>
```

You are basically trying to say "the folder /WEB-INF/googlemaps has a bunch of .tag files for use" - which you don't.

Just browsing the documentation confirms this - it says you should be using this (note the usage of the tld extension):

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/googlemaps.tld" prefix="googlemaps" %>
```

Source: http://www.lamatek.com/GoogleMaps/documentation.jsp#installation

Answer (score 1):

If you set scope to provided in your pom it is not included in the war file and the taglib will not be found. You should change the scope to compile or runtime.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried your suggestion, but it gives the same error as posted in my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The URI should not be /WEB-INF/googlemaps.tld.  It should match the value in the `<uri>` tag in the googlemaps.tld.

Open up the googlemaps.jar, find the googlemaps.tld, and find the `<uri>` tag.  That's the URI you need.

UPDATE:

I just downloaded the googlemaps.jar.  I'm incorrect; the URI is indeed `<uri>/WEB-INF/googlemaps.tld</uri>`.

That suggests that you have to extract the googlemaps.tld file and put it under /WEB-INF in your web context, be it WAR or exploded.

Comment: Extracting is not needed if JAR containing the resource is already in classpath (i.e. `/WEB-INF/lib`).

Comment: Then how else to explain 'File "/WEB-INF/googlemaps" not found'?  It seems like something to try.  I agree that it should not be necessary, because I don't extract .tld for JSTL, but this particular case seems to warrant it.  The JSTL URIs are http; this one is local to the app.